# Haystack SearchQuerySet returns None with content filter

Tags: django-haystack

I have following SearchIndex:

```
class ProductIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True)
    display_name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='display_name')
    link = indexes.CharField(model_attr='link')

    def get_model(self):
        return Product

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects.\
                    filter(last_updated__lte=datetime.datetime.now())
```

And it works fine with queries like:

```
 >>>> SearchQuerySet().filter(display_name='Levis jeans')
 [<SearchResult ... >, <SearchResult ... >, ...]
```

But when I use any content filter, it returns empty list:

```
 >>>> SearchQuerySet().filter(content='Levis jeans')
 []
```

What is wrong?

Also there is no solr Docs with `text` field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: set `use_template=True` for `text` field. Haystack uses django-templates to render documents for search engine.